# Collect tr ids using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Here I have a table structure

```
<table>
       <tr>
          <th>F name<th>
          <th>L name<th>
          <th>Add<th>
       </tr>
       <tr id="test3">
          <td>ssss</td>
          <td>sss</td>
          <td>sss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="test2">
           <td>ssss</td>
           <td>sss</td>
           <td>sss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="test1">
            <td>ssss</td>
            <td>sss</td>
            <td>sss</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

And I want to collect the id's such as

```
test1     test2     test3
```

using jQuery or using JavaScript also

Comment: Have you trird jquery `attr` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {

    $("tr").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    })
})
```

Comment: @ArunrajChandran: Good . But you might see "undefined" also.

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
$("tr[id]").each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Output : test3 test2 test1

It will select `tr` which have `id` attribute.
Also assign some `id` or `class` to your table and use it in selector so that it will select particular table only.

---

**EDIT :**
Just realise that you want ouput in reverse order of appearance so you can use

```
$($("tr[id]").get().reverse()).each(function(){
      console.log(this.id);
 });
```

Output : test1 test2 test3

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/EWTGB/3/)

Comment: Using `table` as part of your selector is probably unnecessary, since that's the only place a `tr` can be, legitimately, found.

Answer (score 2):

Not all your trs have IDs, but you could look at using the `$.each` function from jQuery

```
var ids = new Array();

$('tr').each(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('id') != "undefined") {

        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));

    }

}
```

Comment: @Karna has a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following will loop through all the elements within your table that contains an ID, then append it to a string called idString:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var idElems = $('tr[id]'),
      idString = '';
  idElems.each(function() {
    idString += $(this).prop('id') + ' ';
  });

  console.log(idString);
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/vobpler/pen/vjwAd

*Edit:* Not really sure why you'd want it concatinated in a string, but within the `$.each` you can do whatever you need with the id through `$(this).prop('id')`. See Karma's solution.